# Calculate probability that two people are selected out of chosen 10

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A set of 10 people is chosen without replacement from a population of 100. If A and B are two 
individuals among the 100, what is the probability that the chosen set contains both A and B.

My Thoughts : 
Total number of choices = 100C2 
Now number of ways we can choose 10 people which contains A and B will =
98C2 . So probability = 98C2/100C2

I have to calculate the probability also for the case such that neither A or B occurs. 
I am not 100% sure if my above argument is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your thoughts aren't correct.

For the first part, $\dfrac{\binom{98}8\binom2 2}{\binom{100}{10}}$

For the second part, which you should now do by yourself. there are only $98$ people to select from for the numerator.

Comment: ok Thanks. So probability of neither A or B in the set = 98C10/100C10

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The correct wording, though, should have been neither A **nor** B

Comment: I wanted to calculate probability that either A or B are in the set but not both. So one way to go about is = Total choices - # of choices that contains both A and B - # of choices that contain neither A nor B . I am not sure if this is 100% correct. Also could there be a simpler way to express it ?

Comment: $2\times\dfrac{\binom{99}{10}}{\binom{100}{10}}$, the $2$ multiplier because there are two cases: only **A** missing, and only **B** missing

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite correct.

The total number of equally probable ways of choosing ten from $100$ is $100C10$ or ${100 \choose 10}$

Of these, the number of ways of choosing $A$ and $B$ and eight others ten from $100$ is $2C2 \times 98C8$ or ${2 \choose 2}{98 \choose 8}$.  We can ignore the ${2 \choose 2}=1$ term and so the probability is $$\frac{98 \choose 8}{100 \choose 10}$$

The probability of not choosing either $A$ or $B$ is similarly $\frac{{2 \choose 0}{98 \choose 10}}{100 \choose 10}=\frac{{98 \choose 10}}{100 \choose 10}$

The probability of choosing exactly one of $A$ or $B$ is similarly $\frac{{2 \choose 1}{98 \choose 9}}{100 \choose 10}=2\frac{{98 \choose 9}}{100 \choose 10}$

Answer (score 0):

In your thoughts, somehow  you didn’t include 10 in the formula. If you   take  10 in your consideration, what would you do differently?

[image]

> If A and B both are chosen , we need to select 8 from the rest of 98 people. If neither A nor B are chosen, we need to choose 10 from the rest of  98 people. Therefore,  probabilities  for both chosen =$\frac{C_8^{98}}{C_{10}^{100}},$ neither chosen = $\frac{C_{10}^{98}}{C_{10}^{100}}$.